# Really simple htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have what I thought to be a really simple redirect in my .htaccess file, but it doesn't seem to be working properly...

I want this URL: **loveidee.com/blog** to direct to this URL: https://www.idee-creative.co.uk So I have the following code:

```
Redirect /blog/ https://www.idee-creative.co.uk
```

But this makes it redirect to: https://www.idee-creative.co.ukblog - It just adds the blog onto the end...

I'm sure its something simple I'm doing wrong!!

Heres currently what the whole file looks like:

That doesn't seem to work- I also have a general redirect in there, do you think that first line is effecting it?

Here's what my file looks like...

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.idee-creative.co.uk
Redirect 301 /blog https://www.idee-creative.co.uk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
redirect 301 /blog https://www.idee-creative.co.uk
```

;-)

-- UPDATED --
Yes.. The problem is in the first line..
If you want to redirect alla pages to the home of the new link, use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your-new-domain.com [R=301,L]
```

If you want to redirect to the new website in equal folder, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your-new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work- I also have a general redirect in there, do you think that first line is effecting it? Heres what my file looks like...

Redirect 301 / https://www.idee-creative.co.uk
Redirect 301 /blog https://www.idee-creative.co.uk

Comment: Yes.. The problem is in the first line..
If you want to redirect alla pages to the home of the new link, use this:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your-new-domain.com [R=301,L]

If you want to redirect to the new website in equal folder, try this:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your-new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: I'm trying to sort out my backlinks, so everything that goes to just loveidee.com I want to forward to my new site but then I want to put redirects on more specific pages and directories like the blog directory...  So I don't just want to blanket redirect everything to my homepage?

Comment: To send the users to the homepage use the 2° script code, to send the users to the specific folder->files name use the 3° script code

Answer (score 0):

Try using RedirectMatch instead of Redirect directive. RedirectMatch matches only specific part of the uri and does not automatically append it to target url.

```
RedirectMatch ^/blog/ http://example.com/
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however it still seems to direct me to: https://www.idee-creative.co.ukblog - I don't understand Why? Is it something to do with the main redirect at the top?